# Substitute commas after a certain amount of pipes

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have the following string

```
s = 'AAA\nA|A33, 3|BB,C|CC,C|CC555|AVENUE ,STREET ,POTATO ,JOSPH'
s = 'AAA\nA|A33, 3|BB,C|CC,C|STREET ,POTATO ,JOSPH'
```

What I want to do is take the values after the "last pipeline". And substitute all the commas for '|'.
Important infos, there is a chance of having empty spaces and commas before handed, yes the pipeline varies the amount. (Just noticed now)

My earlier attempt:

```py
print(re.sub(r'[|]{5}',"|",s))
```

Comment: Why not just substitute the `,` for `|` like this `s.replace(",", "|")`?  Are the number of `|` not consistent?

Comment: Please explain why replacing all commas with a pipe is not desirable?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Maybe there can be commas in the first 4 fields that shouldn't be replaced.

Comment: `[|]{5}` matches 5 consecutive pipe characters. Your regexp doesn't even have any commas in it!

Comment: @Barmar There's too many maybes. Maybe the comma and pipe pattern repeats after `JOSPH`. I'd rather ask before engaging in this wild good chase.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Not applyable, there are commas before handed.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Same thing

Comment: @Barmar Yes but i noticed the values of pipelines vary, my idea back than was grabbing, the values after the fifth pipeline and checking on clearly that didnt work (some columns return a little twisted or simply empty)

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1: Please don't remove your attempted code from question otherwise it would look like all answers were posted on a question with no attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `re.sub` with a lambda:

```bash
import re

s = 'AAAA,LTD|A333|BBC|CCC|CC555|AVENUE ,STREET ,POTATO ,JOSPH'

print (re.sub(r'^((?:[^|]*\|){5})(.*)', lambda m: m[1] + m[2].replace(',', '|'), s))
```

**Output:**

```bash
AAAA,LTD|A333|BBC|CCC|CC555|AVENUE |STREET |POTATO |JOSPH
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `[^|]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `|`
    - `\|`: Match a `|`
  - `){5}`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 5 times
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `(.*)`: Match and capture remaining text in capture group #2
- In lambda code we replace `,` with `|` in 2nd capture group only

Comment: As a regex noob, I'd love for you to break up the 2nd bullet point - the first capture group.

Comment: Awesome! Real quick - I guess the braces are the negation "clause" in `[^|]*`. If I were to read that, it'd be start selecting pipes, negate the selection, select everything after, match, repeat, select up to 5?

Comment: `[^|]` is negated character class. Please read a good regex tutorial to understand it better

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code without regex

```
s = 'AAAA|A333|BBC|CCC|CC555|AVENUE ,STREET ,POTATO ,JOSPH'
s.split('|')[5].replace(',', '|')
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string at the `|` characters. Do the comma replacements in the 6th element of that list, then join them back together.

```
fields = s.split('|')
fields[5] = fields[5].replace('|', ',')
s = '|'.join(fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative -I assume you want the first part to remain as it is. This will work for any number of commas or white spaces.
Example strings -

```
s1= r'AAA\nA|A33, 3|BB,C|CC,C|CC555|AVENUE ,STREET , POTATO ,JOSPH'
s2=r'AAA\nA|A33, 3|BB,C|CC,C|CC555|AVENUE ,STREET ,,,, POTATO ,JOSPH'
s3=r'AAA\nA|A33, 3|BB,C|CC,C|CC555|AVENUE ,STREET ,             POTATO ,JOSPH'
```

Code :

```
m=re.sub('[ ]{0,}[,]{1,}[ ]{0,}',r'|',re.search(r'[^|]+$',s)[0])
o=re.search('(.*)[|]',s)[0]
print(o+m)
```

Output:

```
AAA\nA|A33, 3|BB,C|CC,C|CC555|AVENUE|STREET|POTATO|JOSPH
```